# Error reading assemblies in Maven building

Tags: java, maven

Here is my pom.xml file and the error i got when building

Error:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default-cli) on project load-xml-to-s3: Error reading assemblies: No assembly descriptors found.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.tte.s3.load</groupId>
    <artifactId>load-xml-to-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>load-xml-to-s3</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- TOBE USED LATER - DO NOT DELETE. - KC <plugin> <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId> 
                <artifactId>replacer</artifactId> <version>1.5.3</version> <executions> <execution> 
                <phase>prepare-package</phase> <goals> <goal>replace</goal> </goals> </execution> 
                </executions> <configuration> <file>target/classes/somefile.txt</file> <replacements> 
                <replacement> <token>SOME TOKEN</token> <value>SOME VALUE</value> </replacement> 
                </replacements> </configuration> </plugin> -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
                <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.tte.s3.load.driver.Driver</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>one-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>assembly</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>

                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>distribution.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Try moving the configuration for maven-assembly-plugin outside the execution. Nest them under plugin tag

Answer (score 3):

The [`descriptors`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#descriptors) attribute of the `maven-assembly-plugin` expects a path starting from the base directory of your project. For example, if the file is located inside `src/assembly/distribution.xml`, this is the path you should specify.

There is also a problem in the phase you bound the plugin to. Phase [`assembly`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) does not exist, you should use `<phase>package</phase>` instead.

As a side-node, you are using an old version of the plugin (2.2-beta-5). Consider using the latest version instead, which is [2.6](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.6).

Sample configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <!-- no need to specify the groupId, it defaults to "org.apache.maven.plugins" -->
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version> <!-- explicit version is safer for build consistency than implicit -->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind the execution to the "package" phase -->
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/distribution.xml</descriptor> <!-- use the path to the file starting from base directory -->
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Running Maven with `mvn clean install` will invoke the plugin correctly in the package phase.